# Javascript equivalent to .NET's DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to build a validator that will work with .NET's DefaultModelBinder of using DateTime.Parse to convert a string from the form post to a DateTime. I don't want to have to wait until a date has been posted to the server for it to realize it was a bad date.

Currently jquery.validate uses the following code to validate date fields:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
date: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
}
```

However, due to Javascript's terrible Date parser, this:

> 275481/69/100089

Will evaluate as **valid**, to Sep. 12, 275760.

While on the other hand, this:

> 11-19-2013

Will evaluate as **invalid**.

Of course, I understand that C#'s DateTime.Parse() takes things like culture (localization) and leap year into account, and I could live with assuming a fixed (US) culture, and allowing "02-29-2013" on the client and kick it out at the server (ideally not, but it's acceptable).

But I can't believe someone hasn't put together a better date validator to work with C#'s DateTime.Parse() logic.

Maybe someone has, I just haven't found it -- which is why I'm posting here.

And I know I have several ways to go about this -- from incredibly simple (less accurate) to incredibly complex (more accurate), but I'm hoping someone has already gone down this road and found the sweet spot.

Comment: DateJS might be appropriate here, but admittedly, even then, it's not perfect. http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: @GrantH. I thought about date.js, but like you said, it looks like it has its shortcomings. That may be the way I'll go -- probably in combination w/ regular expressions -- if I don't get better suggestions here.

Comment: @SamIam I thought about that, but again, it would either be way too open or way too complex. I may use an open pattern in combination with date.js.

Comment: @JeradRose yeah, really is a shame that there's not anything more robust, seems like a very common problem.

Comment: @JeradRose  What's probably the best solution is to not let users enter in dates free-text.  you might want to give them some sort of calendar widget or enforce a certain datetime format upon them.

Comment: @SamIam Yeah we're doing that, but the datepicker is on a free-text field. Plus, I think it's a better UX to provide an open text field (for keyboardist users) -- never been a fan, as a user, of the date fields that force me to use my mouse to navigate to a date.

Comment: @JeradRose Generally, datepickers seem to come with generic date parsing utilities. (See: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#converting or http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate). `Any+Time` should also be "keyboardable". (If somewhat ugly and space-consuming.)

Comment: @JeradRose : how to convert myDate = '20/06/17' into '20/6/2017 00:00:00' format in javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) seems pretty robust to me. Its [parse](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse) function supports over 150 cultures:

```
Date.parse("February 20th 1973")
```

And in case you need to parse a date string that is not valid in the current culture you can use the [parseExact](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) function:

```
// The Date of 15-Oct-2004
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", ["M/d/yyyy", "MMMM d, yyyy"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty, your best bet is to perform an AJAX hit, and ask your ASP.net web-server to parse the string and return a Javascript date.

Javascript libraries easily get confused with different locales, e.g.:

```
GET /ParseDate.ashx?dateStaring=06/01/34 4:53:05 غ.و&locale=ar-SA
```

Which gets really complicated because:

```
"6/1/34" = November 19, 2012
```

The .NET framework, with Windows behind it, has support for a lot of different locales.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to find two Datetime implementations (one for JS and another for C#) that have similar validation and parsing, have you considered having the client 1)use its own library to validate the date and 2)parse and reformat the date to a C# friendly format?

This would allow you to use [DateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) to get a very flexible front end for date inputs, make it easier to deal with the client side culture, and let your server side deal with a fixed format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing your string into the constructor?

Here's a sample from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var birthday = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
```

Comment: That's what jquery.validate is already doing, I believe (see the code in my OP). This is the one allowing that one crazy date, but not allowing the simply correct date (with hyphens).